# How to define directory structure following packages in project's Scala build definitions?

Tags: sbt

There are two full build definition files in sbt project: `Build.scala` and `Helpers.scala`. They are located in `project` folder.

I'd like to put `Helpers` module into separate sub-folder `project/utils`. When I do `import utils.Helpers` in `Build.scala` it says:

> not found: `object utils`

Is it possible to define directory structure that follows the packages in sbt full build definitions?

Comment: Have you added `package utils` at the start of `Helpers.scala`?

Comment: I don't know if this will fit your needs, but I believe this will work if you move your Helpers module and your utils package into the src folder of your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use `project/src/main/scala/utils` instead of `project/utils`

Answer (score 4):

Sbt builds are [recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#sbt-is-recursive), which means that sbt build definition is built by sbt, applying the same rules as per normal project.

Unlike Java, Scala has no strict relation between the package and folder structure. Meaning you can place your sources wherever you like and it doesn't have to match package declaration. Scala will not complain.

Sbt knows where to search for folders by checking `sourceDirectories` setting key.

You can check it easily by executing `show sourceDirectories`. However this will show the `sourceDirectories` for your actual project. How you can check it for the build? Quite easily, execute `reload plugins`, this will take you to your build. Execute `show sourceDirectories`, and it should show you that it looks for sources in `/project/src/main/scala`, `project/src/main/java` and one more, which is managed sources (doesn't matter for our case). Now you can execute `reload return` to go back to your main project.

Given that you should be able to create an object let's say, named `Helpers` in `project/src/main/scala/utils/Helpers.scala`:

```
package utils

object Helpers {
  def printFancy(name: String) = println(s">>$name<<")
}
```

And use it in your `Build.scala`:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

import utils.Helpers._

object MyBuild extends Build {

  val printProjectName = taskKey[Unit]("Prints fancy project name")

  lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).settings(
    printProjectName := printFancy(name.value)
  )

}
```

You can test it by executing `printProjectName`.

```
> printProjectName
>>root<<
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed May 29, 2014 1:24:16 AM
```

I've stated earlier that sbt is recursive. This means, that if you want, you can use the same technique to configure the sbt build, as you use for configuring building of your own project.

If you don't want to keep your files under `/project/src/main/scala`, but just under `/project/utils`, you can do so by creating `build.sbt` **in your `project` folder**, with following content:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "utils"
```

Just as it is [described in the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Howto/defaultpaths.html#add-resource-directory)

Now even if you place your utils in `project/utils` sbt should be able to find it.