# Folders/packages in sbt ./project folder

Tags: scala, sbt

Looks strange to me, maybe i'm doing something wrong, but when i'm trying to launch sbt it can't find/compile files from folders/packages inside ./project folder, like:

```
root/
  project/
    deploy/DeployModule.scala
           DeployConfig.scala
    Build.scala
```

SBT can't resolve by `build.deploy.DeployModule._` import, but if i move files from deploy folder into project folder it works. So it looks like SBT can't resolve files in nested folders inside project folder?

Comment: Check my answer to another, similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905051/how-to-define-directory-structure-following-packages-in-projects-scala-build-de/23919240#23919240

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sbt's meta build uses the default sbt build (with a few minor extras).  As such, root-level .scala/.java files are picked up, but if you want things in sub-directories, you'll need to place them like so:

```
root/
  project/
     src/main/scala/deploy/
       DeployModule.scala
       DeployConfig.scala
    Build.scala
```