# Split a sbt multimodule project scala build file

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multimodule sbt project, with a basic structure as follows:

```
 - ProjectX
 -- project/ProjectXBuild.scala
 -- moduleA
 -- moduleB
 -- moduleC
 ...
```

Now project/ProjectXBuild.scala has all Project's defined as follows:

```
object ProjectXBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root: Project = Propject( .... ) aggregate(moduleA, moduleB, moduleC)

  lazy val moduleA: Project = Project(.....)
  lazy val moduleB: Project = Project(.....)
  ...
```

What I would like to do, is to move the val's moduleA and moduleB to a separate file because the ProjectXBuild object is getting huge.

I can extract them to ModuleABuild.scala into the ProjectX/project directory. But I would like to move them to a separate package, e.g. ProjectX/project/modules. That doesn't work, sbt doesn't have any project/ subdirectory on it's compile classpath, it seems.

I tried to change that using the recursive nature of sbt and appending a project/modules directory to the classpath in ProjectX/project/project/build.sbt file but I guess either I misunderstood the project/project purpose or I did it wrong.

**To sum up, is it possible** to extract "stuff" from project/MassiveBuildFile.scala to e.g. project/a/ModuleABuild.scala and project/b/ModuleBBuild.scala, etc?

Thanks for any hints. I tried to look at various projects on github, but even https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/project/Sbt.scala is a huge blob of scala code, that seems a little bit unacceptable to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Folders/packages in sbt ./project folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954464/folders-packages-in-sbt-project-folder)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is put settings specific to sub-project `moduleA` in `ProjectX/moduleA/build.sbt` (or any `*.sbt` file in the sub-project directory). You will still have to list the sub-projects in the main `*.sbt` or  `*.scala` build file, but things like dependencies can be defined in each sub-project's build file. In practice, all the build files will be merged to create a single build, but the settings will be scoped properly to each sub-project.

What isn't possible, on the other hand, is to define settings in `ProjectX/moduleA/project/build.scala` or similar. If you want to define settings in `*.scala` files rather than `*.sbt`, they must go in `ProjectX/project/`. However, you can have several `*.scala` files in the project directory, so that could be another way to modularize your build.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this has been answered in

[How to define directory structure following packages in project's Scala build definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905051/how-to-define-directory-structure-following-packages-in-projects-scala-build-de/23919240#23919240) and [Folders/packages in sbt ./project folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954464/folders-packages-in-sbt-project-folder)

All sources simply need to be in project/src/main/scala